# faster alternative to for loop with two-argument function

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a list of csv files called sourcefiles, and I want to apply a function with two arguments to all of files in sourcefiles. Here's what I'm doing now:

```
 for (n in 1:length(sourcefiles)){
      clcc(DT, n)
    }
```

Is there any better way?

Thanks!

Comment: Something along the lines of `lapply(sourcefiles, function(x) clcc(DT, x))`? Note that in this case `x` is already a file name, not an index.

Comment: If you just want to speed things up, you can try R's Just-In-Time compiler. Just add `library(compiler); enableJIT(3)` at the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply` function:

```
lapply(X=aList, FUN=aFunction, otherParameters)
```

This function call `aFunction` for every item of the `aList` passing it as a first parameter and `otherParameters` as the other parameters.

The problem here is that your function `clcc` does not take the sourcefile as first parameter, but there is an easy workaround. If the formal name of the first parameter of the function `clcc` is `DT` (or whatever), you can call lapply by setting the name of it:

```
lapply(X=sourcefiles, FUN=clcc, DT=DT)
```